# HTTP ERROR: 503 Service Unavailable IntelliJ IDEA GWT

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gwt

I created a fresh new GWT Project using IntelliJ Idea Ultimate with sample code in it but I can't seem to run it, at first I had a problem with the DTD file but I managed to fix that its okay, I thought maybe that was the cause of the problem but it's still there. I don't see anything wrong with the web xml file

It was like this by default

> XML web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_4_0.xsd"
         version="4.0">
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>com.studybuddy.studybuddy studybuddyService</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.studybuddy.server.studybuddyServiceImpl</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>com.studybuddy.studybuddy studybuddyService</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/studybuddy/studybuddyService</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Then I tried this because seems like it added a new package in the code which is not there in the file structure, I thought maybe that was the problem but no.

> XML web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_4_0.xsd"
         version="4.0">
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>com.studybuddy studybuddyService</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.studybuddy.server.studybuddyServiceImpl</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>com.studybuddy studybuddyService</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/studybuddy/studybuddyService</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

It still didn't work so I reverted back to the Previous One at the Top
This was the Error Given on the Console

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_221\bin\java.exe" -Xmx512m "-javaagent:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2020.2\lib\idea_rt.jar=59040:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2020.2\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "C:\Users\Username\Programming\Tools\gwt-2.9.0\gwt-codeserver.jar;C:\Users\Username\Programming\Tools\gwt-2.9.0\gwt-dev.jar;C:\Users\Username\Programming\Projects\Software\studybuddy\src;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_221\jre\lib\charsets.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_221\jre\lib\deploy.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_221\jre\lib\ext\access-bridge-64.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_221\jre\lib\ext\cldrdata.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_221\jre\lib\ext\dnsns.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_221\jre\lib\ext\jaccess.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_221\jre\lib\ext\jfxrt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_221\jre\lib\ext\localedata.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_221\jre\lib\ext\nashorn.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_221\jre\lib\ext\sunec.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_221\jre\lib\ext\sunjce_provider.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_221\jre\lib\ext\sunmscapi.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_221\jre\lib\ext\sunpkcs11.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_221\jre\lib\ext\zipfs.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_221\jre\lib\javaws.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_221\jre\lib\jce.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_221\jre\lib\jfr.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_221\jre\lib\jfxswt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_221\jre\lib\jsse.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_221\jre\lib\management-agent.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_221\jre\lib\plugin.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_221\jre\lib\resources.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_221\jre\lib\rt.jar;C:\Users\Username\Programming\Projects\Software\studybuddy\out\production\studybuddy;C:\Users\Username\Programming\Tools\gwt-2.9.0\gwt-user.jar;C:\Users\Username\Programming\Projects\Software\studybuddy\lib\istack-commons-runtime-3.0.7.jar;C:\Users\Username\Programming\Projects\Software\studybuddy\lib\classmate-1.5.1.jar;C:\Users\Username\Programming\Projects\Software\studybuddy\lib\hibernate-commons-annotations-5.1.0.Final.jar;C:\Users\Username\Programming\Projects\Software\studybuddy\lib\antlr-2.7.7.jar;C:\Users\Username\Programming\Projects\Software\studybuddy\lib\FastInfoset-1.2.15.jar;C:\Users\Username\Programming\Projects\Software\studybuddy\lib\dom4j-2.1.1.jar;C:\Users\Username\Programming\Projects\Software\studybuddy\lib\jandex-2.1.1.Final.jar;C:\Users\Username\Programming\Projects\Software\studybuddy\lib\javax.activation-api-1.2.0.jar;C:\Users\Username\Programming\Projects\Software\studybuddy\lib\javax.persistence-api-2.2.jar;C:\Users\Username\Programming\Projects\Software\studybuddy\lib\jaxb-api-2.3.1.jar;C:\Users\Username\Programming\Projects\Software\studybuddy\lib\jboss-logging-3.3.2.Final.jar;C:\Users\Username\Programming\Projects\Software\studybuddy\lib\jaxb-runtime-2.3.1.jar;C:\Users\Username\Programming\Projects\Software\studybuddy\lib\jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec-1.1.1.Final.jar;C:\Users\Username\Programming\Projects\Software\studybuddy\lib\javassist-3.24.0-GA.jar;C:\Users\Username\Programming\Projects\Software\studybuddy\lib\stax-ex-1.8.jar;C:\Users\Username\Programming\Projects\Software\studybuddy\lib\txw2-2.3.1.jar;C:\Users\Username\Programming\Projects\Software\studybuddy\lib\byte-buddy-1.10.7.jar;C:\Users\Username\Programming\Projects\Software\studybuddy\lib\hibernate-core-5.4.11.Final.jar;C:\Users\Username\Programming\Tools\gwt-2.9.0\validation-api-1.0.0.GA-sources.jar;C:\Users\Username\Programming\Tools\gwt-2.9.0\validation-api-1.0.0.GA.jar" com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode -superDevMode -war "C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\JetBrains\IntelliJIdea2020.2\gwt\studybuddy.a6fa6789\studybuddy.720fbc3d\run\www" -remoteUI 7901:IntelliJIdea -startupUrl studybuddy.html com.studybuddy.studybuddy
Running CodeServer with parameters: [-noprecompile, -port, 9876, -sourceLevel, 1.8, -bindAddress, 127.0.0.1, -launcherDir, C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\JetBrains\IntelliJIdea2020.2\gwt\studybuddy.a6fa6789\studybuddy.720fbc3d\run\www, -logLevel, INFO, -style, OBFUSCATED, com.studybuddy.studybuddy]
Super Dev Mode starting up
   workDir: C:\Users\MBUSOK~1\AppData\Local\Temp\gwt-codeserver-920221797952530601.tmp
2020-08-12 14:56:27.774:INFO::main: Logging initialized @2962ms
   Loading Java files in com.studybuddy.studybuddy.
   Module setup completed in 22555 ms
2020-08-12 14:56:49.365:INFO:oejs.Server:main: jetty-9.2.z-SNAPSHOT
2020-08-12 14:56:49.385:INFO:oejsh.ContextHandler:main: Started o.e.j.s.ServletContextHandler@5d4a5149{/,null,AVAILABLE}

The code server is ready at http://127.0.0.1:9876/
Code server started in 23.71 s ms
2020-08-12 14:56:49.416:INFO:oejs.ServerConnector:main: Started ServerConnector@73c674b6{HTTP/1.1}{127.0.0.1:9876}
2020-08-12 14:56:49.421:INFO:oejs.Server:main: Started @24608ms
2020-08-12 14:56:49.619:INFO:oejs.Server:main: jetty-9.2.z-SNAPSHOT
Starting Jetty on port 8888
   [WARN] 
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.get(ConcurrentHashMap.java:936)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.ClassInheritanceHandler.addToInheritanceMap(ClassInheritanceHandler.java:72)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.ClassInheritanceHandler.handle(ClassInheritanceHandler.java:58)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser$MyClassVisitor.visit(AnnotationParser.java:480)
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(ClassReader.java:533)
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(ClassReader.java:400)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.scanClass(AnnotationParser.java:974)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.parseJarEntry(AnnotationParser.java:956)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.parseJar(AnnotationParser.java:909)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.parse(AnnotationParser.java:831)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationConfiguration$ParserTask.call(AnnotationConfiguration.java:163)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationConfiguration$1.run(AnnotationConfiguration.java:548)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:635)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:555)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
   [WARN] 
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.get(ConcurrentHashMap.java:936)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.ClassInheritanceHandler.addToInheritanceMap(ClassInheritanceHandler.java:72)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.ClassInheritanceHandler.handle(ClassInheritanceHandler.java:58)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser$MyClassVisitor.visit(AnnotationParser.java:480)
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(ClassReader.java:533)
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(ClassReader.java:400)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.scanClass(AnnotationParser.java:974)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.parseJarEntry(AnnotationParser.java:956)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.parseJar(AnnotationParser.java:909)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.parse(AnnotationParser.java:831)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationConfiguration$ParserTask.call(AnnotationConfiguration.java:163)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationConfiguration$1.run(AnnotationConfiguration.java:548)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:635)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:555)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
   [WARN] Failed startup of context c.g.g.d.s.j.WebAppContextWithReload@5fbcea03{/,file:/C:/Users/Mbuso%20Kotob's/AppData/Local/JetBrains/IntelliJIdea2020.2/gwt/studybuddy.a6fa6789/studybuddy.720fbc3d/run/www/,STARTING}{C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\JetBrains\IntelliJIdea2020.2\gwt\studybuddy.a6fa6789\studybuddy.720fbc3d\run\www}
MultiException[java.lang.RuntimeException: Error scanning entry module-info.class from jar file:/C:/Users/Mbuso%20Kotob's/AppData/Local/JetBrains/IntelliJIdea2020.2/gwt/studybuddy.a6fa6789/studybuddy.720fbc3d/run/www/WEB-INF/lib/classmate-1.5.1.jar, java.lang.RuntimeException: Error scanning entry META-INF/versions/9/module-info.class from jar file:/C:/Users/Mbuso%20Kotob's/AppData/Local/JetBrains/IntelliJIdea2020.2/gwt/studybuddy.a6fa6789/studybuddy.720fbc3d/run/www/WEB-INF/lib/byte-buddy-1.10.7.jar]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationConfiguration.scanForAnnotations(AnnotationConfiguration.java:536)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationConfiguration.configure(AnnotationConfiguration.java:447)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.configure(WebAppContext.java:479)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1337)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:741)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:505)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.jetty.JettyLauncher$WebAppContextWithReload.doStart(JettyLauncher.java:550)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:114)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:61)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.RequestLogHandler.doStart(RequestLogHandler.java:140)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:387)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:114)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:61)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:354)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.jetty.JettyLauncher.start(JettyLauncher.java:760)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode.doStartUpServer(DevMode.java:636)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase.startUp(DevModeBase.java:898)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase.run(DevModeBase.java:705)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode.main(DevMode.java:432)
    Suppressed: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error scanning entry META-INF/versions/9/module-info.class from jar file:/C:/Users/Mbuso%20Kotob's/AppData/Local/JetBrains/IntelliJIdea2020.2/gwt/studybuddy.a6fa6789/studybuddy.720fbc3d/run/www/WEB-INF/lib/byte-buddy-1.10.7.jar
        at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.parseJar(AnnotationParser.java:913)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.parse(AnnotationParser.java:831)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationConfiguration$ParserTask.call(AnnotationConfiguration.java:163)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationConfiguration$1.run(AnnotationConfiguration.java:548)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:635)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:555)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: This feature requires ASM6
        at org.objectweb.asm.ClassVisitor.visitModule(ClassVisitor.java:130)
        at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.readModuleAttributes(ClassReader.java:724)
        at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(ClassReader.java:544)
        at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(ClassReader.java:400)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.scanClass(AnnotationParser.java:974)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.parseJarEntry(AnnotationParser.java:956)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.parseJar(AnnotationParser.java:909)
        ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error scanning entry module-info.class from jar file:/C:/Users/Mbuso%20Kotob's/AppData/Local/JetBrains/IntelliJIdea2020.2/gwt/studybuddy.a6fa6789/studybuddy.720fbc3d/run/www/WEB-INF/lib/classmate-1.5.1.jar
    at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.parseJar(AnnotationParser.java:913)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.parse(AnnotationParser.java:831)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationConfiguration$ParserTask.call(AnnotationConfiguration.java:163)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationConfiguration$1.run(AnnotationConfiguration.java:548)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:635)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:555)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: This feature requires ASM6
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassVisitor.visitModule(ClassVisitor.java:130)
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.readModuleAttributes(ClassReader.java:724)
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(ClassReader.java:544)
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(ClassReader.java:400)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.scanClass(AnnotationParser.java:974)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.parseJarEntry(AnnotationParser.java:956)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.parseJar(AnnotationParser.java:909)
    ... 6 more
2020-08-12 14:56:52.571:INFO:oejs.ServerConnector:main: Started ServerConnector@374cd3e4{HTTP/1.1}{127.0.0.1:8888}
2020-08-12 14:56:52.571:INFO:oejs.Server:main: Started @27759ms
Dev Mode initialized. Startup URL: 
http://127.0.0.1:8888/studybuddy.html
[ERROR] 503 - GET /studybuddy.html (127.0.0.1) 303 bytes
   Request headers
      Host: 127.0.0.1:8888
      User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:79.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/79.0
      Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
      Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
      Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
      Connection: keep-alive
      Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
   Response headers
      Date: Wed, 12 Aug 2020 12:56:53 GMT
      Cache-Control: must-revalidate,no-cache,no-store
      Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1
      Content-Length: 303
[ERROR] 503 - GET /favicon.ico (127.0.0.1) 299 bytes
   Request headers
      Host: 127.0.0.1:8888
      User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:79.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/79.0
      Accept: image/webp,*/*
      Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
      Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
      Connection: keep-alive
   Response headers
      Date: Wed, 12 Aug 2020 12:56:53 GMT
      Cache-Control: must-revalidate,no-cache,no-store
      Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1
      Content-Length: 299
```

Also Tried using a Different Verion of Jetty since I thought it's problem here though it didn't work also, sam[enter image description here][1]e error, not sure if the Jetty setup that I did was correclty set though.

Also Tried it in Eclipse, latest edition, it also gave me a Jetty 503 Error

How can I fix this????

IMAGE OF THE DIR STRUCTURE
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y15BJ.png

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Intellij plugin is outdated and jetbrains for some reason refuses to open source it or to update it, the best way to get started with GWT is to use [Thomas Broyer maven Archetypes](https://github.com/tbroyer/gwt-maven-archetypes) :

You can generate a project using the following command

```
mvn archetype:generate \
   -DarchetypeGroupId=net.ltgt.gwt.archetypes \
   -DarchetypeVersion=LATEST \
   -DarchetypeArtifactId=modular-webapp
```

then from the root folder in one terminal you execute :

`mvn jetty:run -pl *-server -am -Denv=dev` to run the server

and in another terminal execute :

`mvn gwt:codeserver -pl *-client -am` to run gwt super dev mode -SDM-

then you can access the application in the browser using `http://localhost:8080`